# getting null from data array when pushing data through local storage

Tags: javascript, null, local-storage

I am making a todo list in which I am getting data from local storage.
The problem is that when i store data in data array the data is storing the value = "null"

I want the span value to store in data array but it is not happening;
and showing in todo list
please help me

Code:

```
const item = document.querySelector('#item');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('ul');


item.addEventListener(
    "keyup",
    function(event){
        if(event.key == "Enter"){
            addToDo(this.value)
            this.value=""
        }
    })

const addToDo = (item="")=>{
    var liItem = document.createElement('li')
    liItem.innerHTML=`
    <span>${item}</span>
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    `
    toDoList.appendChild(liItem)
    liItem.addEventListener('click',function(){
        liItem.classList.toggle('dark');
    })
    liItem.querySelector('i').addEventListener('click', function(){
        liItem.remove();
    })
save();
    
}
save();
function save(){
    var liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li span');
    
    data= [];

    liItems.forEach((liItem)=>{
        data.push(liItem.value)
    })
    localStorage.setItem("liItem",JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
}

(
function(){
    const lsItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liItem"));

    lsItem.forEach((lsItem)=>{
        addToDo(lsItem)
    })
}
)()
```

Comment: Can you show us your code (HTML & JS), so that we can help you?

Comment: You are looping `'li span'` and try to get `span.value`, but span does not have `value` property

Comment: In addition, it should be `toDoList.querySelectorAll('li > span');` instead of `document.querySelectorAll('li span');`. And if used with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) one even could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the to be stored `data` ... `const data = [...toDoList.querySelectorAll('li > span')].map(elm => elm.innerHTML)` ... and store it as "item**s**" like ... `localStorage.setItem('todoItems', JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

You are fetch all `li span` elements with `var liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li span');`

Than you loop these elements and try to get `.value` out of it (`data.push(liItem.value)`), but `<span>` elements does not have `value` property, nor you add `data-value` Data API property.

You need to use `.innerHTML` instead:

```js
function save() {
    var liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li span');
    
    data = [];

    liItems.forEach((liItem) => {
        data.push(liItem.innerHTML);
    });

    localStorage.setItem('liItem',JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: sr can you help more with my code of js. I have fixed it

Comment: thanks for your precious time. it worked

Comment: sr the problem is that do you know that when we click the li item it get the dark class but i don't know how to store the class as well as the code